# How can I left align pictures within a picturebox in Acumatica Report Designer?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am using an image with a database source; the image retrieved will vary depending on the criteria in the report.  Some of my images are sized a little differently than others; I would like to have them all print to the maximum possible height for the picturebox, and be left aligned rather than centered if the width of the image varies.

I have set the Styles TextAlign Left and VerticalAlign Bottom and neither appears to make a difference. I am using the "Scale" sizing; other options mess with the aspect ratio or resize in such a way that the image doesn't fit in the space given.

The only thing I can think of do to is to have our graphic designer create a version with whitespace to the right and require all images to be the same size and width.

Is there any other way around this using Report Designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to achieve the desired scaling and alignment with the PictureBox control as it lacks an image alignment property.

> The only thing I can think of do to is to have our graphic designer create a version with whitespace to the right and require all images to be the same size and width.

First step is to scale the image to the maximum size allowed by the aspect ratio. Then add some bottom or right padding to match the control size. The image processing can be automated with a customization. We handle carrier label printing with this method.